# Insert Parent and Detail Records

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two objects that are needed to be inserted at the same time. These objects are `Parent__c` (parent object) and `Detail__c` (detail object). But each time I hit the save button, there's this error showing up:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

Error pertains to this line: `newDetailList.add(d);`

I tried inserting the parent record first without the line items, and it is successfully saved. However, problem occurs when I try to add the detail object part.

Meanwhile, here's what I've worked on so far:

**Apex Class**:

```
public class InsertParentAndDetail {

    public Parent__c newParent{get;set;}
    public List<LineItemWrapper> wrapperList{get;set;}
    public List<Account> selectedAccount {get;set;} 
    public List<Detail__c> newDetailList {get;set;}

    public InsertParentAndDetail(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       newParent = (Parent__c)controller.getRecord();

        if(wrapperList == null) {
            wrapperList = new List<LineItemWrapper>(); 
        }

        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10]) {
            wrapperList.add(new LineItemWrapper(a));    
        }                  
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        List<Account> selectedAccount = new List<Account>();

        for(LineItemWrapper wrapItem : wrapperList) {

            if(wrapItem.selected == true) {
                selectedAccount.add(wrapItem.acc);    
            }

        }

        insert newParent;

        if(newParent.Id != null) {

            for(LineItemWrapper liWrap : wrapperList) {
                Detail__c d = new Detail__c();
                d.Parent__c = newParent.Id;
                d.Account__c = liWrap.acc.Id;
                newDetailList.add(d);
            }

            insert newDetailList;

        }

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + newParent.Id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;

    }

    public class LineItemWrapper {

        public Boolean selected {get;set;}
        public Account acc {get;set;}

        public LineItemWrapper(Account  acc2) {
            acc = acc2;
            selected = false;
        }            

    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Parent__c" extensions="InsertParentAndDetail">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
            var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
                if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                    inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Parent Information">
                <apex:inputField value="{!newParent.Field1__c}" label="Field 1"/>    
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="All Accounts">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="accWrap">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.acc.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.ac.Industry}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

         </apex:pageblock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You probably need a null check before accessing `liWrap.acc.Id` value and initialize the list as well because your list is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialize the `newDetailList` variable.

in the `constructor` or in `save` method initialize before adding the values in it

```
newDetailList  = new List<Detail__c>();
```

Also in order to save the only selected one you have modify this code

```
for(LineItemWrapper liWrap : wrapperList) {
      if(liWrap.selected ){ //add this line. so it will check if it is true then insert detail
                Detail__c d = new Detail__c();
                d.Parent__c = newParent.Id;
                d.Account__c = liWrap.acc.Id;
                newDetailList.add(d);
            }
     }
```

Comment: I've forgotten the selection checking. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

Add this line in your method:-

```
newDetailList= new list<detail__c>();
```

//////////
update your save method with this:-

```
public PageReference save() {

        if(selectedAccount==null){
            selectedAccount = new list<Account>();
        }
        selectedAccount.clear();

       // List<Account> selectedAccount = new List<Account>();

        for(LineItemWrapper wrapItem : wrapperList) {

            if(wrapItem.selected == true) {
                selectedAccount.add(wrapItem.acc);    
            }

        }

        insert newParent;

        if(newParent.Id != null) {

            for(LineItemWrapper liWrap : wrapperList) {
                Detail__c d = new Detail__c();
                d.Parent__c = newParent.Id;
                d.Account__c = liWrap.acc.Id;
                newDetailList.add(d);
            }

            insert newDetailList;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just tried this. Error's gone, but even those that aren't selected by checkbox are saved. How can I insert those that are only selected?

Comment: Hi gaynerys, try above updated code of save method